# Linking to a custom post archive from a category-slug page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying add a ribbon/label to the entries on a category-slug page which link to their specific cpt archive in wordpress... the kind of thing you often see on news websites linking to 'sport' or 'fashion' etc.

I can display the relevant cpt name (by adding to content.php), but can't hyperlink to it by using:

```
<?php   $postType = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
    if ($postType) {
        echo esc_html($postType->labels->singular_name);
} ?>
```

I've tried to fudge it by adding a href"" to parts of the code, but I think I'm exposing my limited knowledge of php here!

Grateful for any help or direction, and hope I've explained the issue clearly.

Thanks

Comment: You could try the get_post_type_archive_link function:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, I had a try with that before and I can't quite get it to work. will keep persevering, but if you have any further suggestions be grateful to hear them.

Comment: What is the outcome of using that function? Does your post type have an archive? Note the has_archive argument by registering a post type: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response Jeffrey - the posts do have an archive. The result of the function is that I'm getting a link back to the category-slug page that the posts are already displayed on, rather than a link to their own cpt archive.

Comment: Just to be sure, you use it like this?: `get_post_type_archive_link( get_post_type($post) );`

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, have made sure to use it that way, but unfortunately no results are showing/ echo'd back.

Wondering if there is a different way to achieve the same result? Perhaps adding the CPT name to the globally available meta display (like tags/categories might be displayed)?

I'm going around in circles, mostly due to my inexperience. Lots to learn.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you echo'ing it? Like `echo get_post_type_archive_link( get_post_type($post) );` Otherwise, try to see what the output of the get_post_type function is.

Comment: Cracked it, Jeffrey thanks so much for all the help. It's taken me ages to get this far. The code which worked: 

`code`    <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( get_post_type($post) ); ?>"><?php $postType = get_post_type_object(get_post_type()); if ($postType) { echo esc_html($postType->labels->singular_name); } ?></a>